# VSCode Debugging with Mocha and ESM Breaking in ESM "compiled" File Instead of Original

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I've been using the ESM module with VSCode and my Mocha unit tests for a long time now, a couple of years at least. Recently when I launch an individual test file in VSCode and set a breakpoint in the test file, it no longer breaks in the original file, but rather breaks in the "ESM compiled" file. I don't really know how ESM works enough to talk about it very well, but the file is compiled/transpiled/transformed in some way with all the imports converted to non-ESModule code. I'm able to step through, and it continues to step through other files as well, but each new file opened is this newly "ESM compiled" version instead of the original file, like it used to be. I only just noticed this recently. So I decided to install and older version of VSCode and see if it still happened, and it turns out it doesn't. With version 1.45.x it works as usual, but with anything newer, I get all these "ESM compiled" files opening up when I step through code.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there any new setting I can set in the newer VSCode versions that would cause this to not happen? It's really more of an annoyance than anything. I can still get my work done, but it's not as streamlined as it used to be. I will probably end up just downgrading permanently until I can find a way to make it not occur in the new version.

So, if anyone has experienced this, or knows of something new in VSCode that would cause this, I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question but actually am using your question as an answer to MY question.  I read somewhere that ESM makes import statements work even if I'm not running in a browser, and overcomes the "cannot import outside module" issue that was forcing me to move the code to an html script section and debug it in a browser.  

So, my question now is:  What json file do you have in your directory that is causing the ESM to be invoked when you press F5?

Comment: @pashute - Sorry I didn't mention this, but in my test command line I use (--require esm) to be able to test with mocha using my ESM'd code. No JSON file, just in the mocha command line. For debugging in VSCode you add the same to your launch profile like: "args": [
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${file}",
                "--require",
                "esm"
            ]